# line breaks not allowed in string literals in database.query

Tags: apex, visualforce

Can  any one please help me out with below query..

```
String query = 'SELECT ID FROM Account WHERE Name = '\+Test+\'';

database.query(query);
```

getting error:-

> line breaks not allowed in string literals

tried this as well

```
String query = 'SELECT ID FROM Account WHERE Name = '\+Test+\'';
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try a query like this:

```
String query = 'SELECT ID FROM Account WHERE Name = \'Test\'';
database.query(query);
```

---

If you find this string modification difficult, then use an [**online tool**](http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/string.html).

Select javascript and enter your query like `SELECT ID FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Test'` and click submit. The output will be:

```
var myvar = 'SELECT ID FROM Account WHERE Name = \'Test\'';
```

Just change `var` to `String` and use in your query.